# Consume web service in sencha touch?

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I am new to sencha touch 2  development.

my doubt is :-

1)How to consume a webservice in sencha touch 2 ?

2)How to pass parameters to webservice method as a input to that service method ?

i request you to help.

any reference or tutorials would help me a lot.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is what you are talking about, here is a good tutorial on getting started: http://miamicoder.com/2012/how-to-create-a-sencha-touch-2-app-part-1/

I personally use a PHP/MySQL backend with an AJAX proxy

Comment: I have gone through this link but they don't tell how to consume services.

Answer (score 0):

I used the ajax request to achieve that goal like this:

```
        var resp = Ext.Ajax.request({
        method: 'post',
        url: url,
        jsonData: {
            'method' : 'Product.search',
            'params' : {
                'pageSize' : 20,
                'pageIndex' : 0
            }
        },
        async : true,
        success : function(response, options){
            var sResult = Ext.decode(response.responseText);
            Ext.Array.each(sResult['result']['datas'], function(obj){
                productModel = Ext.create('transport.model.Product', obj);
                productStore.add(productModel);
            });
            callback();
        },
        failure : function(response, options){

        }
    });
```